# PHP - can't properly read the cookies?

Tags: php, cookies

I save a cookie with value like `131|444|777`

And then I try to make an array of it like:

```
$ausnahmenarray = explode('|', $_COOKIE['ausnahmen']);


foreach($ausnahmearray as $id)
{
    echo $id . '<br>;
}
```

I don't get anything, so I check the cookie value in the browser and see it's like: `131%7C444%7C777`
 why the hell can't the value just be stored the way I saved it and how can I read it the way I saved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookie values are url encoded you just need `urldecode`:

```
<?php
setcookie("ausnahmen", "10|20|30");
$ausnahmenarray = explode('|', urldecode($_COOKIE['ausnahmen']));

foreach($ausnahmenarray as $id)
{
    echo $id . '<br>';
}

?>
```

Comment: Nop don't work this way, should I save the cookie with urlencode first?

Comment: no, cookie values are automatically  encoded: `$temp = urldecode("131%7C444%7C777"); echo $temp;` you should see `131|444|777` as an output. you can check it on this site: https://www.tools4noobs.com/online_php_functions/urldecode/

Comment: I also see 131|444|777 when I just echo $_COOKIE['ausnahmen'] but the | is not recognicable in explode, Just try it exact the way I I did: store this in cookie and then try to create array out of it, you will see

Comment: I changed my code, (it is still the same logic), I tested it and it is works. Use it as a template. You need to run it 2 times because at the 1st time you don't have the cookie value.

Comment: Ok this code rly works, but the way I needed it didn't work. I solved it by storing/reading as JSON